# How to group the same patient name into one cell using rowspan even if we have multiple rows returned to Ajax and displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I need to re-format my html table that is displaying results from an Ajax response.

Usually, each patient may have 1 or more medicine and the table would be like the following:

[image]

What I want is as long as we are displaying the same patient name, I need to group the 3 cells of `Patient 1` into one cell using rowspan.

Here is how I am getting data from server and displaying them into html page using Ajax and jquery:

```
     $.ajax({
        url:'../php/getTemplateThreeData.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {monthVal, nationality},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(resp)
        {
            $("#tempThreeTable #fade").fadeOut(400);
            $.each(resp, function(key, result)
            {
                if(result['nationality']=='something')
                {
                    $('#after_tr').after("<tr id='fade'><td>"
                        +result['patient_name_en']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['nationality']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['registration_number']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['gender']+"</td><td style='width: fit'>"
                        +result['dob']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['patient_address']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['med_name']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['given_quantity']+"</td></tr>");
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#after_tr').after("<tr id='fade'><td>"
                        +result['patient_name_en']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['nationality']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['patient_id']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['gender']+"</td><td style='width: fit'>"
                        +result['dob']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['patient_address']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['med_name']+"</td><td>"
                        +result['given_quantity']+"</td></tr>");
                }
            });
        },
        error:function(resp)
        {

        }
```

The query is the following (I tried to add a subquery to it but it didn't worked because if the same patient appeared 3 times, I will have the count as 2 for the same medicine, and another row with 1 for the other medicine):

```
$getTempThree = "SELECT
    patient.patient_id,
    CONVERT(aes_decrypt(patient.patient_name_en, :encKey)USING utf8mb4) as patient_name_en,
    patient.nationality,
    CONVERT(aes_decrypt(patient.registration_number, :encKey) USING utf8mb4) as unhcr_registration_number,
    patient.gender,
    patient.dob,
    patient.patient_address,
    medication.med_name,
    sum(consultation_med.given_quantity) as given_quantity
FROM
    patient
LEFT JOIN
    visit
ON
    patient.patient_id = visit.patient_id
LEFT JOIN
    consultation
ON
    consultation.visit_id = visit.visit_id
LEFT JOIN
    consultation_med
ON
    consultation_med.consultation_id = consultation.consultation_id
LEFT JOIN
    med_pharmacy
ON
    med_pharmacy.med_pharmacy_id = consultation_med.med_pharmacy_id
LEFT JOIN
    medication
ON
    medication.med_id = med_pharmacy.med_id
WHERE
    consultation_med.clinic_id = :cid
AND
    patient.nationality = :nationality
AND
    DATE_FORMAT(visit.date_of_visit, '%Y-%m') = :getDate
AND
    medication.med_type = :medType
GROUP BY 
    patient.patient_id, 
    medication.med_name
ORDER BY
    patient_name_en DESC
";
```

The JSON response:

> [{0: "someID", 1: "Patient1", 2: "Syrian", 3: "", 4: "female", 5:
>   "1954-10-19",…},…] 0 : {0: "someID, 1: "Patient1", 2: "Syrian", 3: "",
>   4: "female", 5: "1954-10-19",…} 1 : {0: "someID", 1: "Patient1", 2:
>   "Syrian", 3: "", 4: "female", 5: "1954-10-19",…} 2

Comment: sorting result on the basis of `patient_name_en`get the count of each `patient_name_en` and in coloumn of `patient_name_en` at the first occurrence row specify `rowspan=count_of_patient_name_en`.

Comment: okay and how to get the count of each patient_name_en

Comment: can you share sample json response

Comment: Of course, I can add the mysql query too, just give me 2 minutes

Comment: See the edit please

Answer (score 2):

`.reduce` the `resp` into individual patients before iterating over it.

```
const consolidated = resp.reduce((consolidatedSoFar, result) => {
  const id = result.registration_number;
  const thisMedicine = { med_name: result.med_name, given_quantity: result.given_quantity };
  if (!consolidatedSoFar[id]) {
    consolidatedSoFar[id] = result;
    result.medicines = [thisMedicine];
  } else {
    result.medicines.push(thisMedicine);
  }
}, {});
```

Then, while creating the table, give every element except the medicine name/quantity a rowspan of `result.medicines.length`:

```
const rowspan = result.medicine.length;
if(result['nationality']=='something') {
  $('#after_tr').after("<tr id='fade'><td rowspan='" + rowspan + "'>"
                        +result['patient_name_en']+"</td><td>"
```

If there is more than one medicine, append more `<tr>`s each with the two `<td>`s corresponding to the med_name and given_quantity.